# Define a function (?) and show it is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology

Here is a question our teacher gave us:

> Define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $ f(x) = x(1+2x \sin\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \neq  0$ and $f(0) = 0$. 
> Show that $f$ is a differentiable function.

I don't know what exactly I'm supposed to be doing. Can anyone help?

Comment: The function has already been defined for all $x$. You have to check that, for all $c$, $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists in $\Bbb R$. Usually the best way is to compute it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`"define f as <something>"`  just means  `"f is <something>"`. 
You just need to show  that the function $f(x)$ is differentiable where:
$f(x) = x\left(1+2x \sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x\neq0$ ; $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$

It should be doable by applying the definition of differentiability

Comment: Thank you, the define part was the one that confused me. I've solved some problems but first time seeing it phrased like that.